# My dissertation is linked to arXiv but its citations are not found in Google Scholar!

Tags: citations, thesis, google-scholar

My dissertation has been cited in a few good journals, which Google Scholar indexes. I have added my dissertation to Google Scholar and Google Scholar has even linked it to the arXiv version of my dissertation, which I have recently updated. The issue is that none of the citations of my dissertation have shown up in Google Scholar. What could be the cause?

Comment: Why wait for Google to index it? You can add it manually into your "My Citations" list.

Comment: No no, my papers are listed, those citing papers are not counted towards my citation **counts**, not that my paper is not listed in my citations.

Answer (score 4):

Google Scholar, unfortunately, makes no particular guarantees about either timeliness or accuracy. I find that it is best understood as a byproduct of Google's business model, rather than a proper fully-supported tool.

As such, it is not surprising that in my experience sometimes documents will take months, or even more than a year, in order to get properly sorted out by Google Scholar.

In the meantime, I would suggest to not worry about it too much: Google Scholar is *not* a definitive index, and should be used only to get a relative impression of the significance of a body of work, not to seriously evaluate bibliometrics.

Comment: What other tool would you suggest for counting citations *including* not-yet-formally-published papers on arXiv?

Comment: I wouldn't. Citation-counting is an inherently disputatious and imprecise practice. Google Scholar does a pretty good job eventually, so probably you just need to wait a few more months for its algorithm to sort things out.

Comment: I see. I was wondering if there is some alternative. So far, I've used Google Scholar + manual filtering of duplicates, and it wasn't too bad, but I imagine it may get rather tedious in disciplines (or even areas of mathematics) where people publish more.